# C++ перегрузка оператора сложения двух классов. Не находит походящий конструктор

Tags: c++

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Содержание файла .h

class MemoryDevice {

private:
    static int count;

    string name;
    unsigned int ID;
    unsigned int MaxMemorySize;
    unsigned int CurrentMemoryByte;
    unsigned int FreeMemoryByte;
    char* Memory;
public:
    string getName();
    unsigned int getMaxSize();

    MemoryDevice();
    MemoryDevice(std::string, unsigned int);
    ~MemoryDevice();

    MemoryDevice operator + (MemoryDevice);

};
// Содержание файла .cpp

MemoryDevice::MemoryDevice(std::string name, unsigned int MaxMemory = 1024) {
    this->name = name;
    this->ID = count;
    this->MaxMemorySize = MaxMemory;
    this->FreeMemoryByte = MaxMemory;
    this->Memory = new char[this->MaxMemorySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxMemory; i++)
    {
        Memory[i] = -1;
    }
    count++;
};


string MemoryDevice::getName() {
    return this->name;
}
unsigned int MemoryDevice::getMaxSize() {
    return this->MaxMemorySize;
};

MemoryDevice MemoryDevice::operator + (MemoryDevice c1) {

     return MemoryDevice(c1.getName() + " " + this->getName(), (unsigned int)(c1.getMaxSize() + this->getMaxSize()));
};
```

Comment: Кроме того, что значение параметра по умолчанию надо давать в объявлении, а не в реализации, ну и не менее странной передачи объектов по значению, а не по ссылке — не вижу никаких неприятностей... И вообще, это какой-то IntelliSense или как его там, выводит? Не компилятор? Компиляция проходит? Ну так значит, это не ошибка :)

Comment: @Harry 
1) error C2440: return: невозможно преобразовать "MemoryDevice" в "MemoryDevice"

Comment: 2) message : Создать class "MemoryDevice" с помощью конструктора копий невозможно, так как конструкторы копий неоднозначны или отсутствуют

Comment: нет ошибки. Конструктор копирования создаётся автоматом.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Совсем по-хорошему — наличие деструктора, выделение памяти в конструкторе и отсутствие счетчика намекает, что поверхностный конструктор копирования по умолчанию не годится...

Comment: Что-то вопрос очень укорочен. Не виден экземпляр деструктора. Что там может быть не знаю. И ошибка на **jpg** картинке говорит, что конструктор копирования всё-таки есть. Нужно больше информации в вопросе. *Может быть отсутствие деструктора вызывает ошибки?* @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Это ошибка, о которой говорит не компилятор, а IntelliSense, или как там его... Который не видит конструктора копирования, а передачу по значению видит — вот и ругается...

Answer (score 2):

Создайте конструктор копирования `MemoryDevice(MemoryDevice const& other)`, который будет левой стороной выражения.

И лучше в операторе `+` возвращать объект по *ссылке*, а не по *значению*.   Так вы избавитесь от *лишних* вызовов конструктора/деструктора.